# Android - Connecting Android Phone and Gain Span Module

Tags: android, at-command, wifi-direct

I am connectiong a Gain Span wifi module to an android phone and I need the android phone connected as the Group Owner. Currently I am starting the group negotiations from the device that has the Gain Span module connected.

This works with devices such as the Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy s2 and Samsung Galaxy s4. But when trying this with a Nexus 6p it fail all of the time. I currently thing that the issue I am having is the group owner intent on the Nexus 6p is set by default wierdly low and I need to change it before the GainSpan module initiates the group formation.

Problem is I can't seem to find a way of doing this so I still don't know for sure this is my issue.

Edit (13/10/2016):

Now thinking that the issue isn't with the GO intent. I am currently initiating the group negotiations from the gain span module using the commands:
at+p2ppd=mac,0
at+p2pgrpform=mac,listenChan,0,,1,0,0

I would prever to initiate this from the phone side as currently I have to hard code the name of the device to ensure the correct phone is connected to. This means I need to respond to a 'p2p-prov-disc-req' response from the GainSpan side, but I am unsure of how to do this. The programmers user guide says that the correct reponse is the command 'at+p2pprovok' but still im unsure of what else needs to be done.

Also I realise that the question has changed now but still open solution to the original problem. Also I have realiszed the s2 connects every time and it takes allot of attempts to get the s4 to connect and the nexus 6p doesn' connect.

Edit (14/10/2016):

Ok solved the 6p issue, it was because the 6p was connected to a via wifi to my office network. Problem is the other phones where connected to the same network and worked. Any Ideas why only the 6p would behave this way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please paste with the code and error message you get when it "fail all of the time". Also see the [tour] and [aks] page.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html), the higher the number, the higher the odds that you will be the group owner, however this might not be 100% sure. Has the group information been persisted on the phone? Check the WiFi Direct settings on the phone and see if the group has been saved. If so, delete it and try to connect again, specifying the highest number possible.

You can edit the values of your Wifip2pConfig object. Including the groupOwnerIntent

Comment: I know how the group owner intent works and I tried deleting the persisted group when it occured multiple times trying to get this to work. What I would like to know is if there is any way of setting the group owner intent prior to initiating the connection.

Comment: Yeah im realizing that the GO intent is not the issue as looking at the logcat the is successfuly formed with the phone as GO its just something happens after that which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Right ive managed to get it working on the 6p, problem is I had to disconnect it from the office wifi for it to connect. The 6p must do something wierd when being connected to network as the Galaxy s2(which worked always) was connected to the same network and so was the Galaxy s4(which worked some of the time).

So I have solved the problem but it would be more convienient if I could connect to both the internet(WiFi) and the GainSpan Module(WiFiDirect). Any Ideas why this only caused an issue on the 6p.